# Rails - render JavaScript with AJAX or redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails remote `form_for`. For several reasons it is a way better idea to use AJAX to submit the form's contents. If there are errors saving the form I want to be able to render a `.js.erb` file to the page that updates the error div with a partial that displays all the errors.

If there are no errors I want to be able to just redirect and display a flash message.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this in your controller method:

```
if @code
   flash[:success] = 'Success message'
   render js: "window.location = '#{path}'"
else
   flash.now[:alert] = @instance.errors.full_messages
   render partial: 'your/partial'
end
```

Detailed explanation:

- `@code` stands for a variable that keeps the code/information about executed model method;
- `@instance` stands for a model instance;
- `path` stands for a path you want to redirect in case there were no errors;
- `render js: <...>` is used instead of `redirect_to` because you've probably set `respond_to :html, :js` in your controller, so the only way to do a redirect is to use javascript, otherwise you'll get the full rendered page that you are redirecting as an ajax response.
- `flash.now` allows you to access messages  (in your case, error messages) in the same request, as using only `flash` allows it only in the next request.